# Querying Solr Multi valued fields using range

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I have an oddity in Solr with multi valued fields which I can seem to replicate repeatedly.

I have a set of `titles` which have a field called `special_offer_type`. This field is of the type:

```
[
    "5",
    "3",
    "0"
]
```

Querying works fine if I do:

```
special_offer_type:4
```

and I get 5 results back, however, if I do:

```
special_offer_type:[3 TO *]
```

I get only two results back.

It seems Solr is treating ranges on multi value fields as that range having to satisfy all values in the field.

I cannot find a direct reference to this in the document so my question is whehter this behaviour is to be expected or not?

Comment: whats the field type of special_offer_type ? must be int to suport numeric range queries

Comment: @Jayendra It is of type string as shown in the question, I did change it and this part worked, if you wanna post that as an answer I will mark it

Comment: sure .. added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Int field type to support proper Integer range queries

Also check sint vs integer.

[Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaDesign) :-

> Sortable FieldTypes like sint, sdouble are a bit of a misnomer. They
>   are not needed for Sorting in the sense described above, but are
>   needed when doing RangeQuery queries. Sortables, in fact, refer to the
>   notion of making the number sort correctly lexicographically as
>   Strings. That is, if this is not done, the numbers 1..10 sort
>   lexicographically as 1,10, 2, 3... Using an sint, however remedies
>   this. If, however, you don't need to do RangeQuery queries and only
>   need to sort on the field, then just use an int or double or the
>   equivalent appropriate class. You will save yourself time and memory.